# How to display 3 cell per row UICollectionView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, layout, uicollectionview

As per the header, I'm using UICollectionView to display images. I need to display 3 cells per row, something like how [Instagram](http://blog.sellfy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/photo-1.png) does it.

Because there are many screen sizes, I'm getting the width of the iPhone screen, then divide it by 3. However, it does not show as per what I need it to be.

Here are my codes inside the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
private let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 8.0
private let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 3.0
private let heightAdjustment: CGFloat = 30.0    

let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let width = (bounds.size.width - leftAndRightPaddings) / numberOfItemsPerRow
let layout = userDetailCollection.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, width)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line

```
let width = (bounds.size.width - leftAndRightPaddings) / numberOfItemsPerRow
```

with

```
let width = (bounds.size.width - leftAndRightPaddings*4) / numberOfItemsPerRow
```

> As you are not considering spacing between two items & Right insets
>   spacing therefore it is not adjusting in the screen.

```
private let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 15.0
private let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 3.0

let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let width = (bounds.size.width - leftAndRightPaddings*(numberOfItemsPerRow+1)) / numberOfItemsPerRow
let layout = userDetailCollection.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, width)
```

Try this code

Comment: what is LeftandRightMarginPadding

Comment: it is a CGFloat of 8.0

Comment: try increasing its value

Comment: layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, width) try setting the width with very less harcoded  value

Comment: do this layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(30, 30)

Comment: back to square one. HAHAHA! by the way. the `width` value is 123

Comment: let width = (bounds.size.width - leftAndRightPaddings*(numberOfItemsPerRow+1)) / numberOfItemsPerRow  changed code ,,now check

Comment: You can delete "private let heightAdjustment: CGFloat = 30.0" because you don't use it

Answer (score 2):

overriding `UICollectionViewLayout` will let you much more flexibility in creating collectionViews. here is a snippet for `YourOwnCollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewLayout`:

```
- (NSInteger)itemWidth {
    return (self.collectionView.bounds.size.width - (HORIZONTAL_PAD * (NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ROW+1))) / NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ROW; // pad from each side + pad in the middle
}

- (NSInteger)itemHeight {
    return self.itemWidth; // or something else
}

- (NSString *)keyForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *retVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld-%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    return retVal;
}

- (CGRect)frameForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat itemWidth  = [self itemWidth];
    CGFloat itemHeight = [self itemHeight];

    CGFloat originX = HORIZONTAL_PAD + ((indexPath.row % NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ROW)*(HORIZONTAL_PAD + itemWidth));
    CGFloat originY = VERTICAL_PAD + (floorf(indexPath.row/NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ROW)*(VERTICAL_PAD + itemHeight));

    return CGRectMake(originX, originY, itemWidth, itemHeight);
}

- (void)prepareLayout {
    NSMutableDictionary *newLayoutInfo  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *cellLayoutInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSInteger sectionCount = [self.collectionView numberOfSections];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];

    for (NSInteger section = 0; section < sectionCount; section++) {
        NSInteger itemCount = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];

        for (NSInteger item = 0; item < itemCount; item++) {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];

            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes =
            [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
            itemAttributes.frame = [self frameForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSString *key        = [self keyForIndexPath:indexPath];
            cellLayoutInfo[key]  = itemAttributes;
        }
    }

    newLayoutInfo[@"CellKind"] = cellLayoutInfo;
    self.layoutInfo            = newLayoutInfo;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *key = [self keyForIndexPath:indexPath];
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *retVal = self.layoutInfo[@"CellKind"][key];
    return retVal;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSMutableArray *allAttributes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.layoutInfo.count];

    [self.layoutInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *elementIdentifier,
                                                         NSDictionary *elementsInfo,
                                                         BOOL *stop) {
        [elementsInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *indexPath,
                                                          UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes,
                                                          BOOL *innerStop) {

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, attributes.frame)) {
                [allAttributes addObject:attributes];
            }
        }];
    }];

    return allAttributes;
}

- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, floorf([self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]/NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ROW) * (self.itemHeight + VERTICAL_PAD) + VERTICAL_PAD);
}
```

in your mainView add: 
`[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:[[YourOwnCollectionViewLayout alloc] init]];`

*and you're DONE!*

Comment: you can mention that the custom layout can be set in IB as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not considering the `sectionInset` and the `interItemSpacing`. It has some default values which pushes the cells(gives padding). Either you can set the `interItemSpacing` to 0 and `sectionInset` to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` or you have to consider their values during calculation of the cellWidth.

Override these protocol methods for setting the size, insets and interItem spacing

```
optional public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize

optional public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets

optional public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat

optional public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

Comment: I've added as you mentioned. `layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero` and `layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0` But it is still the same.

Comment: Try to set the sectionInset and interItemSpacing in UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods. I guess the setting in property doesn't work sometimes. Also set the size in it's delegate method itself

Comment: hmmm. sorry how do I do that? did you meant `myCollectionView.delegate = self`?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check